# Angular js 1, Routing, locationProvider, 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I managed to remove the hash # from my urls by setting `locationProvider.html5Mode` to **true**, but another issue arose.  Nothing displays, and on my console it gives me a **404 error**.

I am well aware that this question has been asked several times, but I have tried all those solutions without success. Kindly assist.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      //controller:'homecontroller'
    })
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      //controller:'homecontroller'
    })
    .when('/best-prices-buy-phones-in-kenya', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/buy-phones.html',
      //controller:'aboutcontroller'
    })
    .when('/best-prices-buy-phones-in-kenya2', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/buy-phones-htc.html',
      //controller:'servicecontroller'
    })
    .when('/contact_us', {
      templateUrl: 'contact-page.html',
      //controller:'contactcontroller'

    });
}]);
```

Comment: hello. @Sajeetharan kindly find at this https://plnkr.co/edit/bB2pSplv3dRdGlDE9Rv2?p=preview plunker

Answer (score 0):

In Index.html, you no longer need '#' as '  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);' takes care of this. so the href on your links should simply be just a '/' plus the page you require, e.g.

```
  <a href='/home'>
```

or

```
<a href='/best-prices-buy-phones-in-kenya'>
```